# How to use GRANT with variables?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have some troubles with GRANT and variables together in MySql.

```
SET @username := 'user123', @pass := 'pass123';

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO @username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY @pass;
GRANT INSERT (header1, header2, headern) ON `data` TO @username@'%';
GRANT SELECT (header1, header2) ON `data2` TO @username@'%';
```

I'd like to put username and password into variables at the begining of the script and then later use them in GRANT

So instead of this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123';
```

I'd like to use something like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO @username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY pass;
```

I'd really appreciate, if someone could show me the proper statements.
Thank you in advence!

Comment: shouldn't it be `IDENTIFIED BY @pass`, you missed `@`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but this not solves the main problem. :(

Comment: Variables can only be used where SQL allows expressions. GRANT statements don't have expressions in them. You may be able to do it with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET @object = '*.*';
SET @user = '''user1''@''localhost''';

SET @query = CONCAT('GRANT UPDATE ON ', @object, ' TO ', @user);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`spTest`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spTest`( varLogin char(16), varPassword char(64) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE varPasswordHashed CHAR(41);
    SELECT PASSWORD(varPassword) INTO varPasswordHashed;

    # Any of the following 3 lines will cause the creation to fail
    CREATE USER varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY varPassword;
    GRANT USAGE ON test.* TO varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY varPassword;
    GRANT USAGE ON test.* TO varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD varPasswordHashed;

    ## The following 3 lines won't cause any problem at create time
    CREATE USER varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'AnyPassordString';
    GRANT USAGE ON test.* TO varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'AnyPassordString';
    GRANT USAGE ON test.* TO varLogin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD  'AnyPassordString';  
END$$

DELIMITER;
```